# saving results of pandas ols regression to dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am running a regression on a grouped dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.stats.api import ols

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\path_to_file.csv') #path to original file

#groupby POINTID
list1=[]
for i, grp in df.groupby('POINTID'):
    result = ols(y=grp['Date'], x=grp['SWIR32']) #run regression
    #turn regression paramaters to a dataframe
    frame=pd.DataFrame({'POINTID':i, 'R2': result.r2, 'pvalue': result.p_value[1], 'rmse': result.rmse})
    list1.append(frame)
final_frame=pd.concat(list1)
```

but this returns:

`ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

when I change the dataframe creation line to this:

```
frame=pd.DataFrame({'R2': result.r2, 'pvalue': result.p_value[1] , 'rmse': result.rmse}, index=i)
```

this is returned:

```
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Essentially I just want the `POINTID`, r2, RMSE and p-value saved to one dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Series` instead

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.stats.api import ols

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\path_to_file.csv') #path to original file

#groupby POINTID
list1=[]
for i, grp in df.groupby('POINTID'):
    result = ols(y=grp['Date'], x=grp['SWIR32']) #run regression
    #turn regression paramaters to a dataframe
    frame=pd.Series({'POINTID':i, 'R2': result.r2, 'pvalue': result.p_value[1], 'rmse': result.rmse})
    list1.append(frame)
final_frame=pd.concat(list1, axis=1).T
```